# Java DTO into list with jpalq query

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpql, dto

I am working on a project that has many layers and I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. I am trying to query my database for multiple rows and then store them into a list that I can then pass to my rest layer.

When I enter the URL on post man and hit run it fails and says.

**Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowErro**

DAO

```
// get all units

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public List<UnitDTO> getAllUnits()
  {
    String sql = super._jpaql;
    Query query = super._entityManager.createQuery(sql);
    List<UnitDTO> list = (List<UnitDTO>)query.getResultList();

    return list;
  }
```

SERVICE

```
  // Get All Units
  @Override
  public List<UnitDTO> getAllUnits() throws ScorpioException
  {
    List<UnitDTO> list = unitDao.getAll();

    return list;
  }
```

REST

```
  // Get All Units
  @RequestMapping(value="/getAllUnits/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody List<UnitDTO> getAllUnits()
  {
    List<UnitDTO> unitList = getAllUnits();
    return unitList;
  }
```

Comment: Oh yuhp I did forget to add that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your REST controller, it is calling recursively its own `getAllUnits()` method, instead of the one from the service layer .

What you want is rather :

```
  // Get All Units
  @RequestMapping(value="/getAllUnits/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody List<UnitDTO> getAllUnits()
  {
    return unitService.getAllUnits();
  }
```

Comment: That was it . I had List<UnitDTO> unitList = getAllUnits(); Instead of List<UnitDTO> unitList = unitService.getAllUnits();